# Change a WebView Gif programmatically via spinner selection

Tags: android, view, android-spinner, animated-gif

I put a WebView in a fragment in order to show a gif animation. That works perfectly. Here is the WebView class:

```html
public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream is;
    long moviestart;

    public GifWebView(Context context, String gifName) {
     
     super(context);
     Paint p = new Paint();
     p.setAntiAlias(true);
     setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, p);
     
     if(gifName.startsWith("acqua")){

      is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.water);

     } else if(gifName.startsWith("aria")) {
      
      is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.air);
     } 
     
     mMovie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  //System.out.println("now="+now);
  if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
   
   moviestart = now;
  }
  //System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
  int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % mMovie.duration()) ;
  //System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
  mMovie.setTime(relTime);
  mMovie.draw(canvas,(float)this.getWidth()/(float) mMovie.width(),(float)this.getHeight()/(float)   mMovie.height());
  this.invalidate();
 }
}
```

Problems come when I want to stop the gif animation and change it with another gif by spinner selection in my fragment:

```html
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()  {
         
      @Override 
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {    
     
       int posit = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
        
       pertSpinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
       pertSpinner.setValConfirmed(true);
                
       switch (posit) {
      
              case 0 :
             
        toplayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
           view = new GifWebView(getActivity(), "acqua");
        toplayout.addView(view);
             
           break;
             
           case 1 :

        toplayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        view = new GifWebView(getActivity(), "aria");
        toplayout.addView(view);
            
        break;
         }

  }

     @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       // Another interface callback
          
  }
});
```

And this is my XML layout with the toplayout containing the gif:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.firacalc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" >
  
    ... some buttons and the spinner...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pert_spinner"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>
  
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this code the App doesn't change the default GIF. 
Is there a method to set a new GIF programmatically via the spinner?
Any help will be apreciated!!

Comment: `I put a WebView in a fragment` but `GifWebView extends View` - If there is a **WebView** in your code, it's really well hidden. Since I can see no **WebView**.

Comment: Ok.. IT IS A **VIEW CALLED "GifWebView"**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```html
switch (posit) {

    case 0 :

    toplayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    view = new GifWebView(getActivity(), "aria");
    toplayout.addView(view);
    toplayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            
    break;
             
    case 1 :

    toplayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    view = new GifWebView(getActivity(), "acqua");
    toplayout.addView(view);
             
    break;

}
```